# ion-slides won't work before reloading the page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem with an ion-slide since I updated the @ionic-native/... modules to 5.21.5 and @ionic/angular to 5.0.0, so I stripped the slider down as much as possible to find the problem, without success.

Here's my template

```
<ion-slides
    [options]="slideOpts" 
    pager="true"
    (ionSlideDidChange)="updateSlideIndex()">

    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

And the TS part:

```
  @ViewChild(IonSlides, { static: true }) slides: IonSlides;
  slideOpts = {
    effect: 'slide',
    speed: 1000,
    pager: true,
    initialSlide: 0,
  };
```

After entring the site with the slider via routerLink, the slider is loaded but the slide effect isn't working (it looks like only one slide) and the pagination is missing.

After reloading the page (F5), or going back and clicking the same link again, everything forks fine.

Do I have to downgrade everything now?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the issue? I just upgraded my app to v5 and I am using ion-slides a lot, and no issues. Can you explain what is expected and what is not working for you? do you mean you only see 1 slide? and expect several or?

Comment: The issue is/was the following: [@ionic-team/ionic/issues/20356](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20356)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A downgrade back to Angular 8, solved the problem for me.

The problem is/was the following: 
[@ionic-team/ionic/issues/20356](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20356)